# Can't Install RTL8188eus Ubuntu 18.10 File during Installation Show error

Tags: networking, wireless, scripts

I have a wifi usb adapter, the driver install in windows from DVD, but can't install the driver on Ubuntu 18.10. After, Compilation script file shows error. Need Help. The Driver is RTL8188eus, but after installation in windows it show RTL8188FTV something like that, but installation file of Linux shows error during installation. I Uploaded the file on Google Driver Please do check it.

[Uploaded Files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aGOVXOF7xTET6wvSDnbqQ17YJhuzmtGR)

Comment: What drivers are trying to install? Obtained from where? What errors are being shown? Please [edit] the question to add information.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Realtek Semiconductor Corp showing in lsusb

Answer (score 0):

If it is showing as 8188FTV and working then the device might not be RTL8188EUS and actually RTL8188FTV.

Here is the link which will correctly install. I have tested myself. (`git` should be installed before this.) You can use mobile data with usb-tethering option for this. Not large files.

```
git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8188fu
```

Need to make one change in the `rtl8188fu/Makefile` at line no. 445. Replace `"$(MODULE_NAME)"` with `"rtl8188fu"`.

Then simply follow the given instructions, i.e.:

```
cd rtl8188fu
make
sudo make install
```

That's all.